# Can Karate provide the total number of assertions in the report?

Tags: karate

We're considering switching from FitNesse to Karate. In FitNesse when I run a test or entire suite, I get the total number of assertions. e.g. Assertions: 135 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored.
You might say, 'who cares?'. But actually it's helpful to be able to report how many verification points, aka assertions, you have in a suite. 1000 tests with 1000 assertions is different than 1000 tests with 20,000 assertions.
I don't see any way to get that information in a report.

Comment: see linked answer - if you are willing to write some custom code or contribute to karate, great ! else look for other options please